# CakePHP 3 - record can not be saved in my login function

Tags: cakephp, save

Record can not be saved in my login function. I don't know why.
Does anyone know what the problem is? 
Other functions in the controller (add, edit, delete) work without problems.

```
...
class UsersController extends AppController
{
...
    /**
     * Login method
     */     
  public function login()
    {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            $user = $this->Users->newEntity($user,['validate' => false]);
            $user->isNew(false);

            //Last login date
            $user->test = 'abcdef';
            $user->modified = new Time();
            $this->Users->save($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Error'));
    }
   }
...
}
```

Comment: Instead newEntity() use patchEntity() to update your user record

Comment: "_can not be saved_" is not a proper problem description! Even if the problem might be obvious for people that know the CakePHP internals, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead. Show the data that you are working with (ex the user data), the context (ex your entity code), your debugging attempts, and possible errors. Often the problem solves itself when collecting these information.

Answer (score 1):

Why you use `newEntity` ?
Try to remove it and do something liek this :

```
$this->Auth->setUser($user);
            $user->isNew(false);
            $user->validate=false;
            //Last login date
            $user->test = 'abcdef';
            $user->modified = new Time();
            $this->Users->save($user);
```

If it doesn't work try to show entity errors to know why :

Before :  `$this->Users->save($user);`

Do that :

`debug($user->errors());
 die();`

Answer (score 1):

It works on this way:

```
public function login()
        {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $authUser = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($authUser) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($authUser);            
                $User = $this->Users->get($authUser['id']);
                //Last login date
                $User->modified = new Time();
                $this->Users->save($User);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Error'));
        }
       }
```